# Compute the factorial of n using range with two parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compute the factorial of *n* using for loop and an accumulator. I am having trouble with the **range** command and its two parameters - start and end. I am getting invalid syntax error. Here's the code:

```
# factorial.py
#   Program to compute the factorial of a number
#   Illustrates for loop with an accumulator

def main():

    n = int(input("Please enter a whole number: "))

    fact = 1

    for factor in range(1, (n + 1))
        fact = fact * factor

    print("The factorial of", n, "is", fact)


main()
```

Where's the problem?

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Add a colon. `range(1, (n + 1))` -> `range(1, (n + 1)):`

Comment: OMG. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot a `:` after your range function since it is a for loop ^.^